# insert script tag Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, html

when I try to run the following code, I get the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Why?

```js
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.innerHTML="var time = setInterval(flower, 100); var flower01=document.getElementById("flowerContainerDiv"); function flower(){if(flower01.parentNode!==null) flower01.parentNode.removeChild(flower01);}";
var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head");
head[0].appendChild(script);
```

Comment: Look at your quotation marks. The syntax highlighter gives it away. Why are you creating a script tag containing JavaScript instead of directly executing the JavaScript?

Comment: The real question is what are you trying to achieve? Because it looks like you're heading in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are trying to execute javascript why not do that directly in place of doing that by inserting it in script tag, because if this code is going to execute then you already in javascript tag:

```
var time = setInterval(flower, 100); 
var flower01=document.getElementById("flowerContainerDiv"); 
function flower(){
  if(flower01.parentNode!==null)        
    flower01.parentNode.removeChild(flower01);
}
```

otherwise if you still want to do it the cleaner way to can place this code in a function and call, as having script code as string is not readable:

```
function dosomestaff(){
  var time = setInterval(flower, 100); 
  var flower01=document.getElementById("flowerContainerDiv"); 
  function flower(){
    if(flower01.parentNode!==null)        
      flower01.parentNode.removeChild(flower01);
  }
}

var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.innerHTML="dosomestaff()";
var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head");
head[0].appendChild(script);
```

and if you still want to make your code work just change

```
"flowerContainerDiv"    to    'flowerContainerDiv'
```

Comment: Because i wanna remove that node which i dont know when it will appear. Therefore, I use the interval to check whether it extists. Only one thing that i cant understand:why change quotation from double to single can work?

Comment: well, the problem is you can't have double quotes inside double quotes or single quotes inside single quotes, because how string know when it end for example: `"Hi "Barak" "` which one is the end of the string is it the one before B or the one after K or the last one ? but `"Hi 'Barak' "` will work

Comment: Also if you still want to use the double quotes you can skip it like: `"Hi \"Barak\" "` this way you tell the string that this is not the end escape it and find another end OR you can switch them by using single quotes outside `'Hi "Barak" '`  this way double quotes will work inside, please try all of them in console and notice the different and notice if the text will be highlighted or not to understand.

Answer (score -2):

this might help.
1.sometimes the browser doesn't like you putting the script tag in the head
2.you don't have to declare the type you can leave it out